# What is the cardinality of the range $[x, x)$?

Tags: real-analysis

In other words, is $[x, x)$ equal to $\{x\}$ or $\{\}$?

Comment: Under the conventional definitions it is empty as no real number $a$ satisfies $x\le a<x$

Comment: @Jay $x$? The $[$ part implies the range contains $x$.

Comment: $[x,x) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Is it a natural question, because philosopher/scientist Pascal has said "nature abhors vacuum" ;

Comment: The interval notation for end points $a, b$ assumes $a<b$ and a special case is mentioned for degenerate interval $[a, b] $ with $a=b$. I haven't seen the notation $[x, x) $ used anywhere in a textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, for real numbers $a,b,$ the set $$[a,b):=\{t\in\Bbb R:a\leq t<b\}.$$

If $a=x=b,$ then no such $t$ exists, so $[a,b)=\emptyset.$

Answer (score 0):

It's an empty set.

I was under the impression that the brackets imply inclusion and therefore contradict each other in the case of $[x, x)$; but as @FShrike pointed out, the brackets impose constraints on the set and so do not contradict each other.